# Can the Oxford Comma be used with a list of adjectives of the same type?

Tags: orthography, commas, is-it-a-rule, oxford-comma

I was wondering if a list of classifying adjectives of the same type could use the Oxford Comma.

For example: *social, political, and economic problems* is it a correct expression? I was checking a book and the expression they used is *social, political and economic problems*.

Another example: *The tulips were yellow, orange and red*. Can I use *The tulips were yellow, orange, and red*?

Does the Oxford Comma rule apply in those cases? Are they both valid?

Comment: Why do you need the comma there?

Comment:         .

Comment: Commas are matters of orthography, not of grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's fine.

> **The Oxford Comma: Hart’s Rules**
>   ...
>   Examples of the serial comma are:
>
> - mad, bad, and dangerous to know

http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/06/oxford-comma/

There is some ambiguity in the case of your tulip example because it's not clear whether each tulip had three colours or whether you had a mixture of single-coloured tulips, but I'm guessing that's beside the point.

Comment: The idea is that we have three kinds of tulips. What is the best option to express that?