# "Oxford" comma with adjectives

Tags: adjectives, commas

Suppose you have some coordinate adjectives modifying a noun. E.g.

> "the cold, tired, hungry dog."

You could rewrite this as

> "the cold and tired and hungry dog"

but would these

> "the cold, tired, and hungry dog"
>
> "the cold, and tired, and hungry dog"

be acceptable? And would you call the first an oxford comma? I've looked through a bunch of guides for coordinate adjectives. Most of them, like [this](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/) and [this](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives?page=1), never use the last options but don't specifically forbid them. One ([Hart's Rules](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/06/oxford-comma/)) sort of uses it to describe an Oxford comma, but not when modifying a noun. I would appreciate a definitive answer for this if one exists.

Very similar to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204202/can-the-oxford-comma-be-used-with-a-list-of-adjectives-of-the-same-type) question. But their source doesn't make it clear whether the adjectives are supposed to modify a noun or go at the end of a sentence.

Comment: "Acceptable" in appropriate context, because the comma is not grammar, the comma sometimes helps convey the right meaning or disambiguate, **and** generally serves to save a lot of headache for the unwary reader.

Comment: The more complicated question is : why does "the cute little brown dog" NOT need any commas?

Comment: I was a victim of a so-called publishing house's so-called proofreading. They turned ALL my multiple-adjective-before-noun constructions into the third form mentioned by OP.  I had to re-edit the whole book.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Because there's a set order for those adjectives. See [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives). Since rearranging them would be weird they don't need commas between them.

Comment: Thanks!  I only knew this by practice and intuition, not by rule.